# Managing Fixed Cost in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

In short, how do i calculate yearly unit production cost based on fixed cost divided by amount produced?

I am making dashboard in power BI for a video production studio company. They have a fixed cost per month and year based on the salary of the employees, production equipment etc. Lets say that the monthly fixed cost is $20 000. As tables show below i have a column called videos recorded, which i need to tie to the month, and then divided on the fixed cost which will be cost per video on a given month and in summary production cost per video in year 2022. So i want to visualize on a card or table, for July fixed cost were $20.000, we made 30 videos which is $667 per video.

Tables below
[image: Tables below]

Comment: so a calculation of the fixed cost / sum of video sales.

Comment: Please add sample data in [copyable text format](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator).